# Doesn't reduction unnecessarily waste resources?

Tags: discussion

A moderator closed [Doesn't reduction unnecessarily waste resources?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/109507). How can I make it not opinion-based pls?

Comment: Hi, it is important for us to have visibility of what has been asked and answered. Please don't delete questions once you don't need them any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're fine at this point.

While it may seem like a small detail, asking words like "unnecessary" and "waste" tend to invite a lot of opinionated debate about what exactly constitutes waste, what's necessary, and so on. The edits that removed that sort of thing, and focused on the factual portions, make it far more likely that you'll get solid, less-opinionated answers.